# Do I need to go through security again when transiting through Istanbul?

Tags: transit, airport-security, isl

I am travelling from New Delhi to Gothenberg via Istanbul with Turkish Airlines on both sectors. Layover time is 4 hours.

If boarding passes for both sectors were issued in New Delhi, do I need to  go trough security check from arrival to departure in Istanbul again? In my case the arrival and departure are both at Terminal 1 at Istanbul and both flights are operated by Turkish Airlines on one ticket.

Comment: As far as I remember, no.

Answer (score 1):

yes you have to go security screening again to reach from arrival to departure. There is only ine Terminal so everyone in transit has to go through it. This applies to Atatürk Airport. A new Airport is being built and operating as of Oct 2018 if I am not wring. There I do not know.

Comment: The last time I was in Atatürk airport, which was about a year ago, there was no security check for my connection.  It may depend on the authorities' assessments of the security at the arriving flight's point of departure; at some airports they screen people arriving from some destinations but not from others.

Comment: If you haven't already noticed it, you may be interested in our so-called "sister site," [Expatriates.SE].